# Java 8 - toEpochSecond returns same value on different time zone

Tags: java, java-8

The following lines return the same value , even if they are in different time zones

```
System.out.println(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT+04")).toEpochSecond());
System.out.println(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT+02")).toEpochSecond());
```

Am I doing something wrong or I simply misunderstood how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--), `toEpochSecond()` gives a number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**, in conformance to [definition of epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

So that's the expected result: both instant values are the same. After conversion to zoned values, they still both represent **the same point in time**, regardless of time zone. So, converted to seconds since epoch, you get same value.

If I try step by step:

```
// Now:
2017-05-27T23:46:00.324Z
// Now GMT+04:
2017-05-28T03:46:00.324+04:00[GMT+04:00]
// Now GMT+02:
2017-05-28T01:46:00.324+02:00[GMT+02:00]
// Both values represent the same point in time, i.e. that many seconds since epoch (which is defined UTC):
1495928760
```

I hope this will help drive the point home and not bring more confusion: another consequence of this (definition of epoch as UTC-based) is that if you execute `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the same moment in Chile, Uganda, or Mongolia, you'll get the same value (provided system clocks are properly synchronized).

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example to return number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 based on time zone?

Comment: Hm I'm on mobile and won't be able to bring up good code snippets for a while. But also... sorry I don't understand the question. What are the input & output (types & values) of the things you want to convert? (In other words, given X you want Y, please define X & Y)

Comment: @DouaBeri: That's a very odd thing to want to know, and probably suggests that you're trying to do the wrong thing. What are you actually trying to achieve?